# python toggle-able function by a button

Tags: python, button

I am messing around python, and made this simple thing that works on my pc that opens up discord logs in and messages something. I want this to run in the background and make it toggle-able by a button, all tho i have no idea how to do it since i started learning only today!

# log in as dave the goat and message dog dave the dog

```
# positions for my icons below

# 20, 137 chrome
# 307, 48 search bar
# 1674, 105 open discord web
# 687, 685 login
# 681, 517 click on email
# 915, 578 click on the right email
# 220, 310 click on dog
# 654, 1034 click on message

import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.click(20, 137) # click on chrome

time.sleep(0.7)

pyautogui.click(307, 48) # click on search bar

pyautogui.typewrite("discord.com")
pyautogui.typewrite(["enter"])

time.sleep(0.5)

pyautogui.click(1674, 105)

time.sleep(0.7)

pyautogui.click(687, 685)

time.sleep(3.9)

pyautogui.click(220, 310)

pyautogui.click(654, 1034)

pyautogui.typewrite("Dave the goat says hello")
pyautogui.typewrite(["enter"])
```

Comment: This is a hard problem, and the solution you are creating is not one you are going to like very much. Every window will always have to be in the same place, and that's not very desirable.
I HIGHLY recommend learning at least some very basic Python before you embark on this project, you'll be much happier if you do.
There are plenty of free resources online!

Comment: You may want to look into a different python package such as `selenium` or `mechanize` to do the browser automation. That way you don't have to rely on the pixel coordinates of items.

Comment: yes! I have tried various things with selenium, but didn't quite work out. Gonna try tomorrow with different solutions! I did learn variables, arrays and how they work. Also if statements with else and etc. In one day i think progress is quite remarkable!